# Statement with no effect in C

Tags: c

Why does it writte me "statement with no effect use" in the line where there is the "for".

```
r=7;
for (r=7;r<=n1;r+10)
   printf("%d\n",r);
```

Comment: The statement `r + 10` has no side effects.

Comment: Try `r += 10` rather than `r+10`.

Comment: Also, have you actually tried *runnig* this code?

Comment: Thank you but what the difference with r+10

Comment: r + 10 have no side effects.....

Comment: Try. Running. The. Code.

Comment: `r+10` adds `r` with `10` and does nothing with the sum -->  "statement with no effect use" .  It does not change `r`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `r+7` is no assignment.For assignment to take place,you have to write 
something like

`r = r+7` or `r += 7`

Answer (score 0):

`r+10` does not modify `r` so if `n1` happens to be greater than on equal to 7 at the start of the loop, the loop will be infinite, which is probably not what you were trying to achieve. Did you mean `r += 10`, or in other words, increment `r` by 10?